# How to get column values in a Database to jLabels

Tags: java, swing

In my database table, there is a column with different data. What I want is to retrieve all the data in that column and put them on JLabel. i.e in my Database I have.

```
name
Aaron
Baldwin
Gabriel
Harold
```

Now I have a 1 empty jLabel but How do I retrieve the values from the database and place each value in Labels when new data inserted? When new data inserted, new jLabel containing that will data need to create.

What I tried.

```
private void getNames() {

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM details";
    try
    {
        con = Db.getConnection();
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
        {
           jLabel1.setText(rs.getString("name"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what you have tried so for?

Comment: I tried using resultset. but it didn't work.

Comment: post what you have tried what is the output, errors etc.

Comment: actually two ways of binding data into Jlabels. one is databinding and set values from database directly. share what u tried now?

Comment: We are helping to solve your coding problems, but do not solve the problems for you.

Comment: @Balasubramanian How can I do that? Databinding?

Comment: @lakshman I edited my question and added the code.

Comment: May i know what type u r going to use jtable or normal jlabel to bind the values ?

Comment: You are overwriting the content of the label with each row, only the last value retrieved will be displayed. You should use JTable https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html or JList: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Table, below code will:

```
public class Test extends JPanel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();

    JTable billTable = new JTable();
    JTableBinding<UiBillItem, UiBill, JTable> jTableBinding;

    private void init(){
        objects = getNames();
    }

    private List<Object> getNames() {
        // for better to bind, it should return list of details object
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        return list;
    }

    private void initDataBindings(){

        // for table binding
        BeanProperty<Test, List<Object>> uiBillBeanProperty = BeanProperty.create("objects");
        jTableBinding = SwingBindings.createJTableBinding(UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, this, uiBillBeanProperty, billTable);

        BeanProperty<Test, Float> uiBillItemBeanProperty_3 = BeanProperty.create("quantity"); // property need to show 
        jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(uiBillItemBeanProperty_3).setColumnName("Qty");
        // can create multiple property like this 

    }
}
```

Merits:

1. List size automatically calculated. no need to update but when u go for normal jlabel you have to create number of jlabel's want to show
   but don't know size.
2. You can bind the property(variable) inside the class.

Note that you can use GlazedLists also binding based on the condition u can use which one u want.

Below code for Jlabel binding,

```
  public class Test extends JPanel{

    private JLabel lblName;
    Details details;

    public Test(){
        lblName = new JLabel();
        add(lblName);

        init();
        initBinding();
    }
    private void init() {

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM details limit 1";
        try
        {
        con = Db.getConnection();
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        details = (Details) rs;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void initBinding(){
        BeanProperty<Details, Srting> beanProperty = BeanProperty.create("name");
        BeanProperty<JLabel, String> jTextFieldBeanProperty = BeanProperty.create("text");
        AutoBinding<Details, String, JLabel, String> autoBinding_20 = Bindings.createAutoBinding(UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, details, beanProperty, lblName, jTextFieldBeanProperty);
        autoBinding_20.bind();

        // can bind variables 
    }

}

class Details(){

    private Stirng name;

    private final PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(
            this);

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName,
            PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(String propertyName,
            PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(propertyName,
                listener);

    }

    protected void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, Object oldValue,
            Object newValue) {
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(propertyName, oldValue,
                newValue);

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't use a table. Can't I bind data to jLabels?

Comment: you can do but i want to know ur binding code for reference

Comment: I need 3 labels to bind

Comment: before calling databinding method, u can hit the database and bind the value.

Comment: I am getting an error when trying to do that? Can you post the full code with database integration?

Comment: oh, what was the error?. but this way u can bind single object only.

Comment: Can you post the full code with the provided database? Thanks in advance.

Comment: pl. check it. and let me know if your quires